# by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called

Tags: java, jsp

Could you please help me on this issue. Why it is causing an issue?

```
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:344)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:159)
        at org.apache.jsp.sfmain.jsp.integrated_005fapp_005fadmin_005flist_jsp._jspService(integrated_005fapp_005fadmin_005flist_jsp.java:185)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366)
```

Comment: Show us your code which causes this exception.

Comment: Actually i have an export functionality on integratedappadminlist.jsp In that i have added an out.flush(); , in Export action class i am using an ZipOutPutStream, there i am closing the stream.

Comment: Looks like the output stream of the response have been already opened by another piece of code. This can happen in multiple cases, for example a filter attempt to write the response before the view resolver for jsp is called